# YAMLException while deploying efs template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, amazon-efs

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Simple 3 tier web application template
Parameters:
  KeyName:
    Description: The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
  InstanceType:
    Default: t2.micro
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: Must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x
  VpcBlock:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.0.0/16
    Description: >-
      The CIDR range for the VPC. This should be a valid private (RFC 1918) CIDR
      range.
  PublicSubnet01Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.0.0/18
    Description: CidrBlock for public subnet 01 within the VPC
  PublicSubnet02Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.64.0/18
    Description: CidrBlock for public subnet 02 within the VPC
  PrivateSubnet01Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.128.0/18
    Description: CidrBlock for private subnet 01 within the VPC
  PrivateSubnet02Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.192.0/18
    Description: CidrBlock for private subnet 02 within the VPC
Metadata:
  'AWS::CloudFormation::Interface':
    ParameterGroups:
      - Label:
          default: Worker Network Configuration
        Parameters:
          - VpcBlock
          - PublicSubnet01Block
          - PublicSubnet02Block
          - PrivateSubnet01Block
          - PrivateSubnet02Block
Mappings:
  AWSInstanceType2Arch:
    t1.micro:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.nano:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.micro:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.small:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.small:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m1.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m4.10xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c1.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    c1.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c4.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    g2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVMG2
    g2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVMG2
    r3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    d2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    hi1.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    hs1.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    cr1.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    cc2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
  AWSRegionArch2AMI:
    us-east-1:
      HVM64: ami-0ff8a91507f77f867
      HVMG2: ami-0a584ac55a7631c0c
    us-west-2:
      HVM64: ami-a0cfeed8
      HVMG2: ami-0e09505bc235aa82d
    us-west-1:
      HVM64: ami-0bdb828fd58c52235
      HVMG2: ami-066ee5fd4a9ef77f1
    eu-west-1:
      HVM64: ami-047bb4163c506cd98
      HVMG2: ami-0a7c483d527806435
    eu-west-2:
      HVM64: ami-f976839e
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    eu-west-3:
      HVM64: ami-0ebc281c20e89ba4b
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    eu-central-1:
      HVM64: ami-0233214e13e500f77
      HVMG2: ami-06223d46a6d0661c7
    ap-northeast-1:
      HVM64: ami-06cd52961ce9f0d85
      HVMG2: ami-053cdd503598e4a9d
    ap-northeast-2:
      HVM64: ami-0a10b2721688ce9d2
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ap-northeast-3:
      HVM64: ami-0d98120a9fb693f07
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ap-southeast-1:
      HVM64: ami-08569b978cc4dfa10
      HVMG2: ami-0be9df32ae9f92309
    ap-southeast-2:
      HVM64: ami-09b42976632b27e9b
      HVMG2: ami-0a9ce9fecc3d1daf8
    ap-south-1:
      HVM64: ami-0912f71e06545ad88
      HVMG2: ami-097b15e89dbdcfcf4
    us-east-2:
      HVM64: ami-0b59bfac6be064b78
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    ca-central-1:
      HVM64: ami-0b18956f
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    sa-east-1:
      HVM64: ami-07b14488da8ea02a0
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    cn-north-1:
      HVM64: ami-0a4eaf6c4454eda75
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
    cn-northwest-1:
      HVM64: ami-6b6a7d09
      HVMG2: NOT_SUPPORTED
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC'
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcBlock
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-VPC'
  InternetGateway:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::InternetGateway'
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment'
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public Subnets
        - Key: Network
          Value: Public
  PrivateRouteTable01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet AZ1
        - Key: Network
          Value: Private01
  PrivateRouteTable02:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::RouteTable'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private Subnet AZ2
        - Key: Network
          Value: Private02
  PublicRoute:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  PrivateRoute01:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
      - NatGateway01
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable01
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway01
  PrivateRoute02:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
      - NatGateway02
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Route'
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable02
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway02
  NatGateway01:
    DependsOn:
      - NatGatewayEIP1
      - PublicSubnet01
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NatGateway'
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGatewayEIP1.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet01
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-NatGatewayAZ1'
  NatGateway02:
    DependsOn:
      - NatGatewayEIP2
      - PublicSubnet02
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NatGateway'
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGatewayEIP2.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet02
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-NatGatewayAZ2'
  NatGatewayEIP1:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  NatGatewayEIP2:
    DependsOn:
      - VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
  PublicSubnet01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 01
    Properties:
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      AvailabilityZone:
        'Fn::Select':
          - '0'
          - 'Fn::GetAZs':
              Ref: 'AWS::Region'
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PublicSubnet01Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet01'
        - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
          Value: 1
  PublicSubnet02:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 02
    Properties:
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      AvailabilityZone:
        'Fn::Select':
          - '1'
          - 'Fn::GetAZs':
              Ref: 'AWS::Region'
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PublicSubnet02Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet02'
        - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
          Value: 1
  PrivateSubnet01:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 03
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        'Fn::Select':
          - '0'
          - 'Fn::GetAZs':
              Ref: 'AWS::Region'
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PrivateSubnet01Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-PrivateSubnet01'
        - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
          Value: 1
  PrivateSubnet02:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet'
    Metadata:
      Comment: Private Subnet 02
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        'Fn::Select':
          - '1'
          - 'Fn::GetAZs':
              Ref: 'AWS::Region'
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: PrivateSubnet02Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-PrivateSubnet02'
        - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
          Value: 1
  PublicSubnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PublicSubnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PrivateSubnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable01
  PrivateSubnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable02
  ControlPlaneSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Cluster communication with worker nodes
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  LoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer'
    Properties:
      Subnets:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet01
        - !Ref PublicSubnet02
      CrossZone: 'true'
      Listeners:
        - LoadBalancerPort: '80'
          InstancePort: '80'
          Protocol: HTTP
      HealthCheck:
        Target: 'HTTP:80/'
        HealthyThreshold: '3'
        UnhealthyThreshold: '5'
        Interval: '30'
        Timeout: '5'
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref ELBWebServerSecurityGroup
  ELBWebServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP access via port 80
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  AsgLaunchTemplate:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate'
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-launch-template'
      LaunchTemplateData:
        CreditSpecification:
          CpuCredits: Unlimited
        ImageId:
          'Fn::FindInMap':
            - AWSRegionArch2AMI
            - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
            - 'Fn::FindInMap':
                - AWSInstanceType2Arch
                - Ref: InstanceType
                - Arch
        InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
        Monitoring:
          Enabled: true
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref ELBWebServerSecurityGroup
        UserData:
          'Fn::Base64': >
            #!/bin/bash

            yum update -y

            yum install httpd -y

            service httpd start

            chkconfig httpd on

            host_name=`curl -s
            http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-hostname`

            echo "WELCOME TO FEBATECH WEB SERVER $host_name" >
            /var/www/html/index.html  
  ApplicationAsg:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    DependsOn:
      - PublicRouteTable
      - PublicSubnet01RouteTableAssociation
      - PublicSubnet02RouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: ApplicationAsg
      MinSize: '1'
      MaxSize: '5'
      DesiredCapacity: '2'
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref AsgLaunchTemplate
        Version: !GetAtt AsgLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet01
        - !Ref PublicSubnet02
      LoadBalancerNames:
        - !Ref LoadBalancer
  MyNACL:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: NACLforSSHTraffic
  InboundRule:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId:
        Ref: MyNACL
      RuleNumber: 100
      Protocol: 6
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: 172.16.0.0/24
      PortRange:
        From: 0
        To: 65535
  OutboundRule:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry'
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId:
        Ref: MyNACL
      RuleNumber: 100
      Protocol: -1
      Egress: true
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  mySubnetNetworkAclAssociation:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation'
    Properties:
      SubnetId:
        - !Ref PublicSubnet01
        - !Ref PublicSubnet02
      NetworkAclId:
        Ref: MyNACL
        
  MountTargetVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VPC
 
  MountTargetSubnetOne:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet01
      VpcId: !Ref MountTargetVPC
      AvailabilityZone: "ap-south-1a"

  MountTargetSubnetTwo:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet02
      VpcId: !Ref MountTargetVPC
      AvailabilityZone: "ap-south-1b"
 
  FileSystemResource:
    Type: 'AWS::EFS::FileSystem'
    Properties:
      BackupPolicy:
        Status: ENABLED
      PerformanceMode: maxIO
      Encrypted: true
      LifecyclePolicies:
        - TransitionToIA: AFTER_30_DAYS
      FileSystemTags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: TestFileSystem
      FileSystemPolicy:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount"
            Principal:'arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root'
      KmsKeyId: !GetAtt 
        - key
        - Arn
  key:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Id: key-default-1
        Statement:
          - Sid: Allow administration of the key
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Join 
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                  - ':root'
            Action:
              - 'kms:*'
            Resource: '*'
            AWS: "*"

  MountTargetResource1:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
      SubnetId: !Ref MountTargetSubnetOne
      SecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt MountTargetVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup

  MountTargetResource2:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
      SubnetId: !Ref MountTargetSubnetTwo
      SecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt MountTargetVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup

  MountTargetResource3:
    Type: AWS::EFS::MountTarget
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
      SubnetId: !Ref MountTargetSubnetThree
      SecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt MountTargetVPC.DefaultSecurityGroup
 
  AccessPointResource:
    Type: 'AWS::EFS::AccessPoint'
    Properties:
      FileSystemId: !Ref FileSystemResource
      PosixUser:
        Uid: "13234"
        Gid: "1322"
        SecondaryGids:
          - "1344"
          - "1452"
      RootDirectory:
        CreationInfo:
          OwnerGid: "708798"
          OwnerUid: "7987987"
          Permissions: "0755"
        Path: "/mnt/abc/data"
```

The error that I am getting is as follows :

```
 12/11/2020, 1:01:13 PM - Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 590, column 7)

 12/11/2020, 1:01:10 PM - Cannot render the template because of an error.: YAMLException: can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line 589, column 55: ... 'arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root' ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around line 590 you have:

```
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount"
            Principal:'arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root'
```

It should be (space after  `Principal:` missing):

```
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "elasticfilesystem:ClientMount"
            Principal: 'arn:aws:iam::111122223333:root'
```